# Using allocatable, target variables in a derived type

Tags: c++, c, fortran, fortran-iso-c-binding, language-interoperability

I'm binding Fortran code with a C dll, and I would like to have a Fortran array inter-operable with C. I currently have the following subroutine to bind the Fortran array with a C double*:

```
SUBROUTINE Pack_Inputs( Input , In_X )
  TYPE( InputType ) ,               INTENT(INOUT)            :: Input
  REAL(KIND=C_DOUBLE) , ALLOCATABLE , TARGET , INTENT(INOUT) :: In_X(:)

  IF ( .NOT. ALLOCATED(In_X)     ) ALLOCATE( In_X    (Input%Xlen)     )

  DO i = 1,Input%C_obj%Xlen       
     In_X(i) = Input%X(i)
  END DO
  Input%C_obj%X = C_LOC(In_X)    
END SUBROUTINE Pack_Inputs
```

However, what I don't like about the current code is that I am constantly allocating memory, and having to unpack the array when the C dll is entered (partly driven by my reluctance to use the `SAVE` attribute on `In_X(:)`).  I would rather much declare  `In_X` once, inside a Fortran derived type. This leads to the motivation for this post. In this derived type:

```
USE , INSTRINSIC :: ISO_C_BINDING

TYPE , PUBLIC  :: InputType                               
   TYPE(InputType_C)                          :: C_obj   
   REAL(KIND=C_DOUBLE) , ALLOCATABLE , TARGET :: In_X(:)   
   REAL    , DIMENSION(:) , ALLOCATABLE       :: X                    
   REAL    , DIMENSION(:) , ALLOCATABLE       :: Y                    
   REAL    , DIMENSION(:) , ALLOCATABLE       :: Z                    
   INTEGER , DIMENSION(:) , ALLOCATABLE       :: index
   INTEGER                                    :: Xlen                 
   INTEGER                                    :: Ylen                 
   INTEGER                                    :: Zlen                 
   INTEGER                                    :: indexlen
END TYPE InputType
```

I get the error:

```
REAL(KIND=C_DOUBLE) , ALLOCATABLE  , TARGET :: In_X(:)
                                          1
    Error: Attribute at (1) is not allowed in a TYPE definition
```

Is there a way to eliminate this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have encountered this problem before, and the solution that worked for me was to to declare the component as `POINTER` instead of `ALLOCATABLE, TARGET`. I am not sure whether the Fortran standard does not support it, or this feature is just not implemented by the compilers. I was using `ifort v12.0.2.137`.

Would this be an acceptable solution for you? You would then be able to use it as pointer target.

```
TYPE , PUBLIC  :: InputType                               
   TYPE(InputType_C)                          :: C_obj   
   REAL(KIND=C_DOUBLE),DIMENSION(:),POINTER   :: In_X => NULL()
   REAL    , DIMENSION(:) , ALLOCATABLE       :: X                    
   REAL    , DIMENSION(:) , ALLOCATABLE       :: Y                    
   REAL    , DIMENSION(:) , ALLOCATABLE       :: Z                    
   INTEGER , DIMENSION(:) , ALLOCATABLE       :: index
   INTEGER                                    :: Xlen                 
   INTEGER                                    :: Ylen                 
   INTEGER                                    :: Zlen                 
   INTEGER                                    :: indexlen
END TYPE InputType
```

Then, you can associate the `In_X` pointer with target data:

```
In_X(1:Input%C_obj%Xlen) => Input%X(1:Input%C_obj%Xlen)
```

Note that `Input%X` will need to have a `TARGET` attribute as well.

Comment: Perhaps, but maybe I am not applying it right. I get the error:     `IF ( .NOT. ALLOCATED(In_X)     ) ALLOCATE( In_X    (Input%Xlen)     )
Error: 'array' argument of 'allocated' intrinsic at (1) must be ALLOCATABLE`

Comment: Thank you! Your answer provided inspiration, though I took a slightly different approach in that I am using `C_F_POINTER(...)` since I am declaring the size and array contents in C at initialization.  Your note about `REAL(KIND=C_DOUBLE),DIMENSION(:),POINTER   :: In_X => NULL()` did help me get on the right track.

Comment: It is not supported by the standard. The instance of the whole type must be declared target.